# Which folders from /home should I move to a SSD?

Tags: firefox, ssd, disk

I recently bought an 128GB SSD for my laptop. After moving everything in `/` to the SSD I still have 95GB left on it. Now I was thinking about moving some of the content of `/home/`  to the SSD.
As far as I know there are two things to consider

- the speedup gained by moving a file/folder to the SSD drive
- how much the writes to a file will wear down the drive

things that I have considered moving are

- the `.config` folder
- my firefox profile (including cache)
- my thunderbird profile
- some VMs
- PyCharm's config files

Which folders are best suited for being moved? (considering speed and wear)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that these days the SSD-s are really failproof and also not too expensive. So even if the system sonstantly writes on SSD, it would still take atleast 5 years until it actually gets worn out. So for best performance i would move all files, that must be constantly accesible for the system, on the SSD